# NSDictionary getting changed when removing a object from NSMutableArray?

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsdictionary

i'm having the one Dictionary & Array in this i remove a object from Array means it reflect in the Dictionary also 
below is my code,

```
NSMutableArray * planDetailArr;
NSDictionary *singleItemDict;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    planDetailArr=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    singleItemDict=[[NSDictionary alloc]init];}
//Parsing the JSON Response
-(void)responseFun:(NSMutableDictionary *)response
{
            singleItemDict=response;
        planDetailArr=response[@"planDetails_array"];

        //Removing two values from array
        [planDetailArr removeLastObject];
        [planDetailArr removeObjectAtIndex:0];
}
```

in above code i remove the values in the array only.when i print the array & dictionary after removing the Values it reflects in the Dictionary also help me Please..

**Note**:As well as i print the response it also getting removed.

Comment: Why are `planDetailArr` and `subgleItemDict` declared as global, rather than instance variables?

Comment: no i wanna to use in other methods also like table view count

Comment: That is no reason to make them global.  This will cause issues down the road.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to get the copy of dictionary. Since they are pointing to same object actual object's values change.

```
singleItemDict=[response copy];
planDetailArr=[response[@"planDetails_array"] mutableCopy];
```

this will fix the problem.

Comment: hi meth,i've one doubt in this copy,mutablecopy these are ok and this fixed my problem but y it reflect in this,i'm Removing the object in array it reflecting in Dictionary How??? even these two are different Datatype & Variable Name also then y it remving in Dictionary aslo@meth

Comment: @TestiOS Since array is inside dictionary, and you are pointing the array not allocating space and creating new one, when you change the array's composition and since it is inside the dictionary, dictionary's structure is effected by this change too.